# curl command in omnipay

Tags: php, laravel-5, payment-gateway, omnipay

I wanted to check when we are calling hitting any API URL through omnipay what will be the final command created by omnipay? I debugged and checked in files of guzzle when omnipay trying to hitting the API.

I debugged files of guzzle HTTP library

```php
omnipay\common\src\Common\Http\Client.php - "request" method called

omnipay\common\src\Common\Http\Client.php - "sendRequest" method called

php-http\guzzle6-adapter\src\Client.php - "sendRequest" method called

php-http\guzzle6-adapter\src\Client.php - "sendAsyncRequest" method called

guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php" - "sendAsync" method called

guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php" - "prepareDefaults" method called

guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php" - "transfer" method called

guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php" - "applyOptions" method called
```

I am expecting that what command finally created by omnipay.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Question is : When omnipay is sending request through guzzle then it is hitting or creating command. So I want to know where it is getting created like we can when final endpoint with prepared values are going to hit. I hope it's cleared. The issue is I am able to send request through Omnipay but not getting any response from the third party. When I contacted third party vendor they are getting request correctly. When I am trying to hit through command line I am getting proper response.